# Let $\varphi:G\to H$ and $\psi:H\to K$ be homomorphisms. Show that $\ker(\varphi)\unlhd\ker(\psi\circ\varphi).$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

Let $φ: G → H$ and $ψ: H → K$ be two homomorphisms.

(a) Show that $ψ ◦ φ: G → K$ is a homomorphism.

(b) Show that $ker(φ)$ is a normal subgroup of $ker(ψ ◦ φ)$.

SOLUTION

For any $h ∈ ker(φ)$ and $g ∈ ker(ψ ◦ φ)$, the conjugate $ghg^{−1}$
is in ker(φ):

$φ(ghg^{−1}) = φ(g)φ(h)φ(g^{−1}) = φ(g)φ(g^{−1}) = e$, $e$ being the identity element.

I've managed to do question (a) but struggling with question (b). The solution in my textbook is given below but I'm struggling to understand it. I thought for g and $ghg^{-1}$ to be conjugate $g$ and $h$ both had to be in the same group.

Comment: They are. They are both in $\ker(\psi\circ \varphi)$.

Comment: Then shouldn't the conjugate be in ker(ψ∘φ) rather than ker(φ)?

Comment: Let me read again: "(b) Show that $\ker \varphi$ is a normal subgroup of $\ker(\psi\circ\varphi)$". What does this mean, to you?

Comment: Need to prove ker φ is a subgroup of ker(ψ∘φ) and prove xyx^-1 is in ker φ where x is in ker(ψ∘φ) and y is in ker φ. But unsure how to use the conjugacy theorem when x and y both have to be from the same group.

Comment: Provided that it's already been established that $\ker\varphi$ is a subgroup of $\ker(\psi\circ\varphi)$, the proof you've quoted in the post is sound.

Comment: So if they are both from the same group ker(ψ∘φ) then shouldnt the conjugate also be in ker(ψ∘φ) rather than in the subgroup of that ker φ?

Comment: A fortiori, yes.

Comment: So how do we prove its in the subgroup ker φ?

Comment: In the aforementioned way.

Comment: This only proves its in ker(ψ∘φ)

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: Homework solutions from tutor

Answer (score 1):

$\operatorname{ker} \varphi$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $\operatorname{ker} \varphi \subseteq \operatorname{ker}(\psi \circ \varphi)$, so $\operatorname{ker} \varphi$ is also normal in $\operatorname{ker}(\psi \circ \varphi)$ by the following lemma:

> Let $N \unlhd G$ and $N \subseteq K$ where $K \leq G$. Then $N \unlhd K$.

Comment: Wanted to better understand the answer given in question.

Comment: @rpp As my answer indicates, $ker \varphi \subseteq ker (\psi \circ \varphi)$ so they belong to the same group...